# "CommandError: No iOS devices available in Simulator.app" Expo error

Tags: react-native, terminal, expo, macos-sonoma

I updated my Macbook to Sonoma and I really regret it. I have an Expo App created using the latest versions of everything. I had just created it before the OS upgrade. Everything was running fine. After the upgrade, a series of problems keep coming up.

- First I was no longer able to create or modify files on VS code. I fixed that using sudo chown and giving my current user permission to modify my project's folder
- Then git vanished. I had to reinstall it and it started working again.
- Then Xcode stopped working and updated itself. With the new xcode came a new simulator with the latest iPhones. Everything runs fine, but VSCode does not seem to recognise the simulator. When I run Expo and use the i command to launch the app in the iPhone simulator, I get the error *CommandError: No iOS devices available in Simulator.app* If I run it using a --tunnel, it does not load on my iPhone through the Expo Go app either.

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this? I searched online and could not find any mention of this error anywhere. It's been a nightmare!

***Update***
I ran `killall Simulator` then `open -a Simulator` and finally `npm start` and it did the trick. Finally! I also added an iPhone 14 Pro to the simulator. I haven't tried on the iPhone 15 Pro yet. I'll leave it as it is for now while it's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you need add a new simulator device.
You can see how do this on here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-developer-tools/adding-additional-simulators